# How do I refactor two forms with same fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two forms - one uses `form_for` and is like this:

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  ...
  ...
```

There is another form which looks alike except that it uses `form_tag`

```
 <% form_tag send_request_path do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name, '' %>
  <%= email_field_tag :email, '' %>
  ...
  ...
```

Since all the fields are identical, I want to abstract them into a partial but could not because one is tied to an object while the other is not. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Why are the forms identical? What is this `send_request_path`? Something user-related?

Comment: The send_request_path sends an email request. It has no direct relationship with user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The send_request_path sends an email request. It has no direct relationship with user.

In this case, you **shouldn't** be DRYing those two forms. It is so-called "accidental duplication". Two forms turned out having the same structure *by chance*.

Since the two things are not related, chances are good that implementations will diverge as time goes on. What are you going to do then? Insert `if` conditions in a shared partial?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the field for the FORM code in the Partial.for example

You can write a FORM Object in one file like:

**first_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @users, url: { send_request_path } do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: {f: f} %>
<%end%>
```

**second_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @posts, url: { send_request_path } do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: {f: f} %>
<%end%>
```

And the Partial.

**_form.html.erb**(PARTIAL)

```
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.email_field :email %>
```

As you can see that, I am using the **locals** to pass the form object to the Partial. By this way you can use the same form field file for two forms.(You can also use form_tag instead of form_form in both file.)

Comment: Giving up form_for to use a shared partial is not worth it. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, can you explain why? Give `-` and write `is not worth it` is not very informative.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you explain why it is not worth to use a shared partial for the form_for?

Comment: @Vikram: as Bartek explains in his answer, `form_for` is more intelligent. For example it correctly picks create/update action, depending on object being new or not. With `form_tag` you will have to do this yourself. Why write your own logic when it's been done in the framework already?

Comment: @Vikram: also you misread my comment. I said that you shouldn't make two implementations equally dumb only to use a shared partial (which one shouldn't use here anyway)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ya, I agree that form_for picks create/update action, depending on object being new or not, that's why I have mentioned the url in the form, like `url: {controller: 'some_controller', action: 'some_action'}` so it will go into that action right.

Comment: @Vikram: oh, I totally missed that. Now this where you misread the _question_. I am tempted to downvote you again, because it answers some another question, not the one asked. :) User form __doesn't__ go to send_request_path. Also, there's no resource for `@posts`.